# Question about Ganache

Tags: ganache

After I updated my Ganache the account addresses and the Mnemonic change everytime I start Ganache.
The option "Autogenerate HD Mnemonic" is disabled.

Do you know a way to keep the same account addresses and the same Mnemonic?

Thank you for your help.

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Ganache UI's Quickstart workspace. It *should* persist the mnemonic if you enter one and disable the Auto Generate option. You should open a new issue on the Ganache repo!

Comment: @Pierre, feel free to upvote and mark as accepted! :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `-m` to set the mnemonic so it is the same every time.

From the docs:

```
-m or --mnemonic: Use a bip39 mnemonic phrase for generating a PRNG seed, which is in turn used for hierarchical deterministic (HD) account generation.
```

So ...

```
ganache-cli -m "the quick brown fox ..."
```

Hope it helps.